# How to export and import component from one module to it's children module in angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5.

I have a module called `PostLoginPartnersModule` and within it I have a component called `SearchUsersComponent` and another module `ListingUsersModule`. I want to use
`SearchUsersComponent` in a component which exist in `ListingUsersModule`.

I am getting an error:

> core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type SearchUsersComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PostLoginPartnersModule and ListingUsersModule! Please consider moving SearchUsersComponent to a higher module that imports PostLoginPartnersModule and CareGroupModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes SearchUsersComponent then import that NgModule in PostLoginPartnersModule and ListingUsersModule.
>   Error: Type SearchPatientComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PostLoginPartnersModule and ListingUsersModule! Please consider moving SearchUsersComponent to a higher module that imports PostLoginPartnersModule and ListingUsersModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes SearchPatientComponent then import that NgModule in PostLoginPartnersModule and ListingUsersModule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only declare a `Component` in a single module. Import the module that declares and exports this `Component` into the modules that use it. So in this particular case `ListingUsersModule` should import `PostLoginPartnersModule`. `ListingUsersModule` shouldn't redeclare `SearchUsersComponent`.

It might be that from a design point of view importing `PostLoginPartnersModule` into `ListingUsersModule` doesn't make sense. In that case make a third module declaring and exporting the `SearchUsersComponent` (and other shared components) and import that module in both of the other modules.

I'd recommend not having directories with modules inside the directory of another module. This can be confusing.

Comment: And remember to add your component in the `exports` declaration of your NgModule !

Comment: @DavidWalschots Thanks for helping out. Was not aware of this. Creating a third module within PostLoginPartnersModule worked. But I was not able to use application's shared modules (like FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule) in searchUsers component. SearchUsersComponent is part of PostLoginPartnersModule and PostLoginPartnersModule  has imported shared module. To fix this I imported sharedModules in the newly created sub module of PostLoginPartnersModule as well. I couldn't understand why this is required. Thanks for your time and knowledge :)

Comment: @Simer Whatever is imported in one module is not automatically imported in another module. Therefore, you might want to consider creating a [shared feature module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) which imports and exports `FormsModule`, etc. Then simply import the `SharedModule` into your other modules.

Comment: @DavidWalschots I have sharedModule in application. Now when I created another module sharedComponentsModule(to share searchUsers componenr) within PostLoginPartnersModule then I have import sharedModules in  sharedComponentsModule in order to use shared modules in searchUsers component whereas searchUsers component is itself part of PostLoginPartnersModule. I know I am not clear enough just wanted to state my problem. I have updated stackblitz to describe this. Though nothing is functional in demo but created sharedModule and subsharedModule to explain my doubt. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @Simer SO is not a debugging service. By changing your StackBlitz, you've now effectively made your original question difficult to answer/follow. Please don't do that. If you have more questions open a new question. Be sure to follow the [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) and follow my advice on not having modules below modules. Also make sure to put all components at or below the directory of the module. Not within another parent/sibling directory.